# не работает шейдер в юнити

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры, shader-graph

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а новичок в шейдерах и сделал такой простенький шейдер, в окошке main preview все нормально отображается, а вот на сцене объект на который наложен шейдер становится невидимым. с чем это может быть связано?